# Unable to verify XML Signature using Apache Santuario 1.4.6

Tags: java, xml, security, apache

I am looking for some help in solving a problem I have in verifying an XML Signature using the Apache Santuario Java library version 1.4.6.  I have a client/server solution where the client signs a DOM document before sending the document to the server.  I apply the signature to the document like so:

```
public static void applySignature(X509Certificate cert, PrivateKey privateKey, Document doc)
{
    try
    {
        XMLSignature sig = new XMLSignature(doc, 
                                            "", 
                                            XMLSignature.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA);

        sig.addResourceResolver(new XmlSignatureResolver());
        doc.getDocumentElement().appendChild(sig.getElement());

        Transforms transforms = new Transforms(doc);
        transforms.addTransform(Transforms.TRANSFORM_ENVELOPED_SIGNATURE);
        transforms.addTransform(Transforms.TRANSFORM_C14N_WITH_COMMENTS);

        sig.addDocument("", transforms, Constants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA1);

        sig.addKeyInfo(cert);
        sig.addKeyInfo(cert.getPublicKey());

        sig.sign(privateKey);
    }
    catch (XMLSecurityException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I verify the signature as follows:

```
public static boolean verifySignature(X509Certificate cert, Document doc)
{
    boolean validSignature = false;

    try
    {
        Element nscontext = createDSctx(doc, "ds", Constants.SignatureSpecNS); 

        // Remove any attributes of Signed Info
        Node signInfoNode = XPathAPI.selectSingleNode(doc, "//ds:SignedInfo", nscontext);

        int numAttributes = signInfoNode.getAttributes().getLength();
        if (numAttributes > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numAttributes; i++)
            {
                String attrName = signInfoNode.getAttributes().item(0).getNodeName();
                signInfoNode.getAttributes().removeNamedItem(attrName);
            }    
        }

        Element sigElement = 
            (Element) XPathAPI.selectSingleNode(doc, "//ds:Signature", nscontext); 
        XMLSignature signature = new XMLSignature(sigElement, "");

        signature.setFollowNestedManifests(true); 
        signature.addResourceResolver(new XmlSignatureResolver());

        validSignature = signature.checkSignatureValue(cert);

        //  Remove the signature
        sigElement.getParentNode().removeChild(sigElement);            
    }
    catch (XMLSignatureException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (XMLSecurityException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (TransformerException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return validSignature;// validSignature;
}
```

The problem I have is that when I verify the signature on the server (it works on the client if I verify right after applying the signature), I get the following warning:

> 2011-11-12 18:30:27 Reference [WARN] Verification failed for URI
>   ""
>  2011-11-12 18:30:27 Reference [WARN] Expected Digest:
>   EEl+J/jsY8Im2rgjsozBXRxkQjQ=
>  2011-11-12 18:30:27 Reference [WARN]
>   Actual Digest: Y7C0HCjugZbegkZT4E8A7Bd4qm0=

Thanks for the help,
 
Ernie Burlison

=============

The code I use to send the dom from the client to the server is:

```
                // Use a Transformer for output
                TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "utf-8");
                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");

                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(m_SenderOutput);

                m_Logger.debug("Transforming...");
                transformer.transform(source, result);   
                m_SenderOutput.flush();
                m_Logger.debug("Transform complete...");
                m_ClientSocket.shutdownOutput();
```

The code that reads the dom on the server side is:

```
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

                m_Logger.debug("Parsing Document");
                Document doc = db.parse(m_SenderInput);
                m_Logger.debug("Received DOM");
```

The dom before the apply signature is similar to the following (data is encrypted before signature is applied):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SmMessageSet xmlns="urn:ccsds:recommendation:service_management:schema:sccs:R1.0" xmlns:ns2="urn:ccsds:recommendation:navigation:schema:ndmxml:R1.5"><xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc"/><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/><xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>VosyFTcuAkzo6WPPLnnM2Nka+gpyD9r2cNy3fbSX8RjGg5dKktK9SGZAar5t3ci2mU6Nw9Ski2Td
g1WNei+kgns6vFET5Ff8m5/VIO24sBz30DPO5cAwfLax0slTjZWDRu7XXs/ORSK2PrB8B8qaO+me
W5iPLXjkkL4LnLwZfIvCSdG3JJoOTUhR6CstquTejRBLvTdvry8jB2RncjpV244eng7Bmk7HWcNd
Mz20DujfX14MTyKAQcVAgUhM9MpisveiDRdKYtXWCkma2NcUhpxqzjyPtyJtHVJQfaPZ2kla2NQV
DcMPUvmM+V0Y3kI5NBZq1vlIAg1i5JsZRniB+Q==</xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherData></xenc:EncryptedKey></ds:KeyInfo><xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>8UCDr2ZzDvD5JczkPU7UnxRYBdxs6ZgL5s2ksHyn/FZvBVSwYh6o/Rnx41fnN6uygcylW++zoxSq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</xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherData></xenc:EncryptedData></SmMessageSet>
```

The XML is identical after the applySignature and after the SignedInfo is modified within verifysignature method.  The problem appears to be with the SignedInfo Referenced Items when I send the document over a socket; somehow the transformation that occurs during verification is adding 46 bytes causing the check to fail.

Not sure where this is coming from.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's not directly related to your error, but it will cause failure later on: you're not supposed to remove or alter anything within the SignedInfo element. The final signature value is computed over the digest of the canonicalized SignedInfo element. So if you change anything there before validating the signature, you are definitely going to break it.

As to why your document digest is invalid - this could have multiple reasons, hard to analyze from just guessing. What would help is if you could post the unsigned document here, then I could tell you what the correct digest value would be, at least...

Comment: Thanks for responding. The code removes the attributes of SignedInfo because I was trying to get the document to look the same as it came out of the applysignature on the client side. I was thinking that the transforms I was performing on the dom to send the data over a socket may have added the additional atrributes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with SignedInfo but the KeyInfo node.  The KeyInfo node had a namespace attribute added that was not there when the original signature was applied.  Removing the KeyInfo attribute prior to checking the signature value fixes the problem I was seeing.

Answer (score 0):

short answer: in the original question, add `doc.normalizeDocument();` at the start of `applySignature`, so before adding the signature.

more info:

I know this is an old question, but I had a similar problem that was not solved by any of the answers. 
In fact, I think one of the answers is wrong, it says the problem is in the verification. However, I believe it is in the signing! I hope that putting my experience and solution here helps someone with a similar problem.

I was generating an XML document, then signing it. I tried to sign with both Apache Santuario. When that didn't work, I switched to javax.xml.crypto.dsig.

Both of these methods generated XML documents that where not correctly signed when I checked them with Santuario, and with external tools!

First an example of the signed XML I tried to generate:

```
<signed-envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="somenamespace" xsi:schemaLocation="someshemelocation">
   <object xml:id="object0">
      ...
   </object>
   <signatures>
      <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
         ...
         <SignedInfo>
            <Reference URI="#object0">
            ...
         </SignedInfo>
      </Signature>
   </signatures>
</signed-envelope>
```

The namespaces of `signed-envelope` is crucial! Everything worked perfectly without namespaces. But when I added the needed namespace to `signed-envelope`, the signing generated an XML file which could not be verified. Also not by an external tool (which means that signing failed, not verification)!

Santuario offers great debugging output with log4j. This output showed that wh:en verifying, the following namespace was added to both the `<object>` and the `<SignedInfo>`:

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

This is the correct way to verify! One of the answers here suggests it is not correct and tries to fix it, but this is in fact correct. The problem here lies not with verification, but with signing!

The problem is that Santuario showed that this namespace was NOT added when signing the document! This led me to believe that something was wrong with the `Document` object I generated.
My XML document was generated with a namespace added to the root element like this:

```
rootElement.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation", "some_namespace");
```

After a lot of searching, I found out that `doc.normalizeDocument()` solved a similar issue. I tried it, and everything works!
I have no idea why `doc.normalizeDocument()` makes everything work, but now I can sign correctly with both Apache Santuario, and javax.xml.crypto.dsig. So they both need this to sign correctly.